# programmatically compile template and append to element

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In an Angular 1.4.7 app I want to programmatically compile a string of HTML, passing it a scope. This compilation is performed inside a directive, and I want to append the result of the compilation to a child of the directive's element.

I'm current attempting to do this like so:

```
 // htmlTemplate is a string of HTML that contains expressions,
 // directives, etc.
 var htmlContentScope = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'};
 var compiledHtml = $compile(htmlTemplate)(htmlContentScope);
 var htmlContentTarget = $element.find('.html-content');
 htmlContentTarget.html(compiledHtml);
```

However this results in the following error

> scope.$new is not a function

Possibly the reason for this is that `htmlContentScope` is a plain-old JS object, rather than an Angular scope object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, you need to pass in an Angular [Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), not an normal object or hash. This is important so that Angular can enforce watches, keep track of the scope's ID number in internal data structures, and access the root scope.

As in the "Usage" section of the [$compile docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage):

> #### Returns
>
> `function(scope, cloneAttachFn=, options=)`
>
> a link function which is used to bind template (a DOM element/tree) to a scope. Where:
>
> - scope - A [Scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) to bind to.
> - ...

So assuming you have access to a `scope` parameter, because this is likely in a `link` or `postLink` function:

```
var htmlContentScope = scope.$new();
htmlContentScope.foo = 'foo';
htmlContentScope.bar = 'bar';
var compiledHtml = $compile(htmlTemplate)(htmlContentScope);
$element.find('.html-content').html(compiledHtml);
```

Of course, if this weren't in a directive or if you wanted a clean slate free of parent scope interference, you could extend the `$rootScope` instead, but in a directive it's much more correct to use the scope you're given.

Comment: Should I create a new scope programatically with `$rootScope.$new` and attach my variables to it? If you could edit your post with a correction to my snippet, that'd be much appreciated.

Comment: @Donal, $scope.$new() or $rootScope.$new() depending on what you want and attach variables to it. Like `let childScope = $scope.$new(); childScope.var1 = 'value1'; childScope.var2 = 'value2';`

Comment: @Dónal Because you don't actually show us where you create or populate your `htmlContentScope`, you haven't given me anything I can correct! GProst's creation of `childScope` is as good of a starting point as I would come up with.

Comment: @Dónal Do you have access to rootScope or any other scope object from that function? Or can you, if you inject it?

Comment: @JeffBowman yes, I can inject `$rootScope` because this code is in a directive

Comment: @Dónal Edited above.